# How can I access text that is passed from previous activity by freezestext?

Tags: android, textview

I have an activity with a TextView and some text in it. I used `android:freezesText="true"` so when the screen is rotated, the text from the TextView will remain.
However, when I try to access that text using `textView.getText()` I don't get anything, yet the text is on screen. 
Can I access this text? Where is it really placed if not in the TextEdit?

activity.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counterTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:freezesText="true"
    tools:text="4"
    style="@style/CounterTVStyle"/>
```

Activity.java:

```
private int counterStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    counterTV = findViewById(R.id.counterTV);
    Integer currCounter;
    try {
        currCounter = Integer.parseInt(counterTV.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        currCounter = null;
    }
    counterStart = currCounter != null ? currCounter : 1;
}
```

I tried printing the result of `counterTV.getText()`, and got an empty string.

Thanks

Comment: put your code please

Comment: Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have to wait until the layout complete the rendering, so if you want to get the value of your `EditText` after screen rotate (and recreate the activity) you could use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    counterTV = findViewById(R.id.counterTV);
    counterTV.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                counterTV.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                Log.d("your_tag","Your value here : " + counterTV.getText().toString());
                Integer currCounter;
                try {
                    currCounter = Integer.parseInt(counterTV.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    currCounter = null;
                }
                counterStart = currCounter != null ? currCounter : 1;
                        }
        });

}
```

If you don't want to do that and you don't need your `Activity` recreate every time that you rotate the phone, you could add this in your Activity manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Activity LifeCycle when the screen is rotated is as follows

```
onPause
onSaveInstanceState
onStop
onDestroy 

onCreate
onStart
onRestoreInstanceState
onResume

//CODE BELOW
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
    bundle.putInt("counter",currCounter);
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
        counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");
    }
}
```

P.S: You need to make the counter variable global.